# What is the equivalent of mysql_real_escape_string for the Pawn language?

Tags: regex, escaping, mysql-real-escape-string, pawn

I need the regex code for [Pawn](http://www.compuphase.com/pawn/pawn.htm). I need a code which I can use with preg_replace, too.

Also what i use, is worse...

So, my code is.

```
$text = preg_replace('/([\\\\\|\'|"])/', '\\\$1', $text);
```

Is this right? This code would replace the in PHP documentation given characters etc. But it replaces all \ :/ \n etc., too!

Have you a Code, which only replaces the following characters?
http://de3.php.net/manual/de/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php

\x00, \n, \r, \, ', " und \x1a

Comment: You're trying to replace mysql_real_escape_string with a call to preg_replace?  Bad, bad idea.

Comment: The Language "PAWN" haven´t a mysql_real_escape_string or a Function like this. Because this, i must use regex for this. Couldn´t you help? :/ In PHP the Function exist, also why i should replace it ^^ its only for "pawn", Sa-MP Language etc.

Comment: OK, wait, so your question is **What is the equivalent of `mysql_real_escape_string` for the [Pawn language](http://www.compuphase.com/pawn/pawn.htm)**? If so, how are you connecting with it to a database in the first place?

Comment: I changed the Title.
Yes, this is my Question.

To a Database i connect with a Plugin.
But this is no matter... I need only the regex Code :/

Comment: That plugin does not offer any sort of parameter escaping?

Comment: _I need a regex code for Pawn_ - can you expand on that? What do you want that regex to do? It isn't clear from your question at the moment. (I've edited it as best I can, but if you can edit further, that would be helpful).

Comment: @deceze: i said: no matter / worse / etc.... you dont know?

Comment: @halfer: The Regex should have the same Function like mysql_real_escape_string... Also it should replace \x00, \n, \r, \, ', " und \x1a. My Code replaces all \ etc. or i´ve been right??? Is My Code okay/good?

Comment: Are you connecting to a MySQL database using Pawn, and needing an equivalent of `mysql_real_escape_string` in Pawn?

Comment: ........... I need a Regex Function....

Comment: Couple of things: firstly, people don't get your messages unless you call them by name (@halfer). Secondly, I asked you to clarify what you needed this function for, so people can give you a relevant response. Please do so `:)`

Comment: @halfer: okay :) i need this function for escape strings like 'Hello ' " you'. This String i would save with MySQL. And because the String is sad, i need an Escaping ^^ :/

Comment: @Charles - if you're sure `pawn` is an inappropriate tag, I won't rollback again. But this is indeed a question connected to that programming language.

Answer (score 1):

Bearing in mind I've not heard of Pawn until now, ten minutes of web searching found [this](http://pastebin.com/VTyARFn1) and [this](http://forum.sa-mp.com/showthread.php?t=56564) - both of which I think answer your question. This is assuming that you are looking for a way to escape strings in the Pawn language.

As @Corbin says, it is not a good idea generally to do escaping on your own, unless your language/library doesn't offer an escape function. But this library appears to offer `mysql_real_escape_string`, just like PHP.

Answer (score 0):

What are you creating Pawn scripts for? If it's [SA-MP](http://www.sa-mp.com/), you should simply use the [mysql_real_escape_string](http://wiki.sa-mp.com/wiki/MySQL#mysql_real_escape_string) function, which is provided by all released MySQL plugins.

Escaping MySQL with regex is a really bad idea, as different MySQL servers have different requirements. It'd also be slower.